# Python String replacing special characters

Tags: python, string, replace, special-characters

I need to replace "-" with spaces (but not more than 1 consecutively, and strip everything at the beginning and at the end) and delete any other special character, some examples:

```
    "Example-1" ---> "Example 1"  
    "Example - 2"---> "Example 2"  
    "Ex amp le-(3)"--->"Ex amp le 3"  
    "--Example%s,,4 "--->"Examples4"
```

Resolved

(I have to edit the question because I have just 8 reputation and I can't answer my own question for 5 more hours)

I resolved this question like this:

```
 my_string = re.sub('[^\w -]', '', my_string).replace('-', ' ').strip(' ')
 subsMade = 1
 while subsMade > 0:
     (my_string, subsMade) = re.subn('  ', ' ', my_string)
```

Comment: Definitely a job for regular expressions.  http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with zigg, you'll need reg ex for that. You can find a gentle introduction here: http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/index.html#re.intro (check 'Street Address' case study, it shares some similarities with what you want to do).

**EDIT:**

I'm not a reg ex guru, but...

```
import re

pattern = "[- ]+"
re.sub(pattern, " ", your_string)
```

This will parse your first two examples.
I'm not sure if all you need can be done in a single pattern... May some wise men come along.

Comment: As an answer, you really should spend more effort in explaining how such a regexp would look like.

Comment: I wasn't for the school or any homework at all, anyway thank you for your constructive comment Paulo.